# AWS Amplify: InvalidOauthConfigurationException

Tags: json, kotlin, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am building my application with AWS Amplify service and I am facing several issues.
I used kotlin language with android.

```
class AuthActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = AuthActivity::class.simpleName

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth)

        Amplify.addPlugin(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
        try {
            Amplify.configure(applicationContext)
            Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Initialized Amplify")
        } catch (error: AmplifyException) {
            Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Could not initialize Amplify", error)
        }

        Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
            { Log.i("AmplifyQuickstart", "Auth session = $it") },
            { error -> Log.e("AmplifyQuickstart", "Failed to fetch auth session", error) }
        )

        Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI(
            this@AuthActivity,
            { Log.i("AuthQuickStart", "Signin OK = $it") },
            { Log.e("AuthQuickStart", "Signin failed", it) }
        )
    }
}
```

The above code is my custom activity.

I would like to build a Login page with `Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI`, however when I run this code, Logcat shows an error message:

> InvalidOauthConfigurationException{message=The Oauth configuration is missing or invalid., cause=null, recoverySuggestion=HostedUI Oauth section not configured or unable to parse from amplifyconfiguration.json file.

How can I fix it up and what should I do for this?

The following is the `amplifyconfiguration.json` file:

[image]

I have tried modifying `amplifyconfiguration.json` file, however, it still doesn't work.

I reconfigured AWS Amplify as well.

Comment: Hi @장진호 
Have you got the solution?